# Can you use power analysis to find if the null hypothesis is true rather than not?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, sampling, p-value, statistical-power

So in power analysis I have only ever seen it explained like in this statquest video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VX_M3tIyiYk
Where you have two distributions and you're trying to see if they are really unique or if they come from the same underlying distribution. Can power analysis be used to change this situation round a little - say all you have is one distribution, can you find the probability that it is not actually a different distribution, just with samples that happen to be concentrated to (for example) the right of the actual distribution? I.e. imagine you make a drug to get rid of flu faster. You have a drug but no, you give group A the drug but don't do a placebo group. You plot the distribution for how quickly group A got better. Now you get a second group (group B) and give them all the same pill, but you don't know if that pill was the drug or a placebo (but everyone got the same pill!). You then plot a distribution of how long it took them to get better and the distribution looks like the distribution of group A but very slightly different, that pill could have been the placebo one right, just everyone in group C happened to get better a bit faster than average and thus the distribution looks like the one which took the drug.

Is there anyway to quantify how different the distribution of group B would need to be for us to confidently say that the group did not take the drug but instead were given a placebo? And also to quantify how confident we are. To be more clear, imagine the distribution of group B came out as very similar to group A, it's highly likely they took the drug but they could still have taken the placebo and all happened to get better fast. On the other hand the distribution comes out totally different to group A, it's highly unlikely the group took the drug but they still could have and all just taken ages to get better despite the drug being effective. Assume group A was huge thus the distribution is very well known, however the size of group B will likely be a parameter of how confidently we will be able to say if the distribution is the same or not. Please leave a comment if any of this isn't clear and I'll try clarify!

Comment: You may be interested in [tag:equivalence] tests such as [tag:tost]. The R package [PowerTOST](https://github.com/Detlew/PowerTOST) may also be of use to you.

Comment: What the OP is describing is the motivation for a traditional Bayesian procedure.

Answer (score 0):

The first idea that comes into my mind would be a one-sample test, where you use your sample A to get an idea of what is the distribution of recovered patients and then compare remaining groups to said distribution.

A crude idea would be some t-test or Wilcoxon test for one sample but, then you would be comparing your response only to one parameter from A. Maybe Kolmogorov-Smirnov, where you can indeed compare samples and check if they come from the same distribution, would be a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

What you're referring to is the "effect size" aspect of a power analysis. A power analysis relates the sample size, type I error rate, type II error rate (1-power), and effect size. We sometimes design experiments by fixing the desired type I and type II error rates, giving an expected effect size that we should be able to capture, and then finding a sample size that is sufficient to accomplish these goals. But you can also use power analysis to fix any three of the four variables and solve for the last one - given the type I and type II error rates and a sample size, you can calculate the effect size that you're likely to be able to capture. You'll always have a non-zero type II error rate, so you can't be *sure* that you'd reject the null hypothesis even given a large effect size, but you can use this approach to figure out what effects you're likely to find.

You can use this approach to help decide if "absence of evidence" is "evidence of absence" or not. Given a particular dataset of fixed sample size, you can determine how "useful" the dataset is in finding effects with desired error rates. You may find that your sample size is very small and the effect sizes you're able to reliably find are unrealistically large - suppose in your drug example, you find that your sample size only allows you to reliably identify an effect of a 1000-fold decrease in recovery time, which would be enormous. Finding no significant difference between placebo and drug in this scenario is utterly unsurprising - you've failed to reject the null hypothesis of no difference, but it certainly is not evidence that there is no difference, since your data is insufficient to find anything but absurdly large effects. On the other hand, if you have a very large dataset that is sufficiently powered to pick up on a 1% change in recovery time, seeing no significant difference is actually good evidence that there really is no effect - you very likely would have found even small effects if they existed.